# Express $u(x,y)+v(x,y)i$ in the form of $f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need to express $f(z)$ from the form $\color{blue}{u+vi}$ to the form $\color{blue}z$ for example if: $g(z)=\frac{1}{x+yi}$ so $ =g(z)=\frac{1}{z}$

> $$f(z)=\underbrace {x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-2x}_{=u(x,y)}+\underbrace {\bigg(y\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-2y+1\bigg)}_{=v(x,y)}i$$

**My try:**

$$x\underbrace{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}_{=|z|}-2x+y\underbrace{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}_{=|z|}i-2yi+i$$

$$x|z|-2x+yi|z|-2yi+i$$

> I'm stuck here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x\underbrace{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}_{=|z|}-2x+y\underbrace{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}_{=|z|}i-2yi+i=|z|(x+iy)-2(x+y)+i=z|z|-2z+i$$

Answer (score 1):

$x|z|-2x+iy|z|-2yi+i=|z|z-2z+i$

Answer (score 1):

$$x|z|-2x+yi|z|-2yi+i=|z|(x+yi)-2(x+yi)+i=|z|z-2z+i=z(|z|-2)+i$$
Hence: $$f(z)=z(|z|-2)+i$$