# Express $\frac{1-x}{(x-1)^2+y^2}-\bigg(\frac{y}{(x-1)^2+y^2}\bigg)i$ in the form of $f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need to express $f(z)$ from the form $\color{blue}{u+vi}$ to the form $\color{blue}z$ for example if: $g(z)=\frac{1}{x+yi}$ so $ =g(z)=\frac{1}{z}$

> $$f(z)=\underbrace {\frac{1-x}{(x-1)^2+y^2}}_{=u(x,y)}+\underbrace {\bigg(-\frac{y}{(x-1)^2+y^2}\bigg)}_{=v(x,y)}i$$

**My try:**

$$f(z)=\frac{1-x-yi}{(x-1)^2+y^2}$$

$$=\frac{1-\overbrace{x-yi}^{=\bar z}}{\underbrace{x^2+y^2}_{=|z|^2}-2x+1^2}$$

$$-\frac{1-\bar z}{|z|^2-2x+1}$$

> I'm stuck here

Comment: What is the question and what do you have to prove?- Question is unclear.

Comment: @Aniket See here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522679/express-ux-yvx-yi-in-the-form-of-fz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** $$f(z)=\frac{1-x-yi}{(x-1)^2+y^2}$$
$$=\frac{-[(x-1)+iy]}{[(x-1)+iy][(x-1)-iy]}$$
$$=\frac{-(z-1)}{(z-1)(\bar z-1)}$$

I hope the rest can be understood.

Comment: it seems wrong ( $x-1-iy=\bar z-1$).

Comment: @EmilioNovati Oops, made a mistake.Thanks for correcting..:-)

Answer (score 2):

When $z=x+i y$ then

$$f(z) = \frac1{1-\bar{z}} $$

Comment: Can you explain how?

Comment: @Nehorai: (sorry, my Hebrew is a little rusty) The denominator is $ (1-x + i y)(1-x-i y)$, while the numerator is $1-x-i y$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint ( to prove the answer of @RonGordon):

$$
f(z)=\frac{1-x}{(x-1)^2+y^2}-\bigg(\frac{y}{(x-1)^2+y^2}\bigg)i=
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2+y^2}\left(1-x-i y \right) = \frac{\bar u}{|u|^2}=\frac{1}{u}
$$
for $u=1-x +iy=1-(x-iy)=1-\bar z$